# How do I display a SharePoint list from another site?

Tags: data-view-web-part

I need to display a list from the parent site collection root as a Data Form Web Part in a child site in SharePoint 2010. [This article](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/display-sharepoint-list-site-data-view-web-part/) seems to be talking about what I need.

But I'm not able to create a data source to the list in the parent from SP Designer. I'm logged in as administrator. Under Data Sources, I only see my site's objects, and the same thing under More Data Sources, and there's no option to add a new data source.

Is there a permission that needs to be changed to allow a site to see the root site's objects and create data sources to them? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For SP 2013,2016, check this [Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've noticed you've marked your post with 2010, so this makes sense as to why you cannot *easily* connect to a different datasource.  In a nutshell, [here's the answer](http://sympmarc.com/2010/11/02/using-a-datasource-in-a-data-view-web-part-dvwp-in-a-different-site-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/).

I'm really not sure why the 'Connect to another library' option was removed.  Seems to me, like it was a feature often used.  If it's any consolation, at least we are still able to code it.

Comment: That's the right trick, Matt! There's an article somewhere from the SPD team that said the WebURL approach was "unreliable", so they removed it. That's bunk; it *always* works.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I'm kind of lost as to why useful features are removed. It took me a bit of work to figure out the article was for 2007, and then realize it's gone in 1010. If we structure our sites correctly, we want some lists at the root that will be filtered by sub-sites.