# How to use a List from a different SP2013 site as a web part?

Tags: list, web-part

I'm brand new to SharePoint 2013, and only have a basic working knowledge so far.

My manager would like to take a List of projects from one site group, and use it on our department's home page.  I have tried using a Web Part > Page Viewer, but I want to display just the list, not the whole page.

Is this doable through the browser?  Or do I need to use SPDesigner and/or some scripting?

Comment: You may use the Data View Web Part and link it to your library / list

Comment: This question is already answered here - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/how-do-i-display-a-sharepoint-list-from-another-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you just need to use the same list structure to add your own department projects, so you can use **`save the list as a template`** in list setting.

[image]

Then create a new one in your department site from this template.

**If** you need to display the same list content and both departments can use and add items in the same list so, check

- [Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)
- [SP 2016 - Display list from Parent site in sub-site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226651/sp-2016-display-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site/226657)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!  The Data View Web Part is the solution to my problem, and I just found out I can't implement it because I don't have the right permissions :(  But thankfully, I now know who I need to talk to make it happen.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

as a quick fix you can use `script editor` and use REST API to achieve your goal

[here you  can read and learn about  REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest3)